# Update Primary Live tile for every one hour?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, live-tile

I'm updating my Live Tile when user open the app using the OnNavigated method like below:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
        if (null != tile)
        {
            StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
            data.BackTitle = ContentHead;
            data.BackContent = ProductText;
            tile.Update(data);
        }
    }
```

But if the user doesn't access the app, LiveTile will not be updated. I don't want this.

I wish to update the LiveTile for every one hour, `ContentHead` and `ProductText` should be updated on the LiveTiles for every one hour.

Can anyone please guide me how to achieve this one?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a BackgroundAgent in to your solution and use it to set the Live tile Periodically. Add a ScheduledTaskAgent to your Solution. This periodic update happens about every 30 mins. Refer to these links on how to implement that.
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Working_with_Live_Tiles_on_Windows_Phone

Comment: The sample provided by you is for Windows Store apps, not for WP!

Comment: Oopz My bad. I will edit that. But follow the wiki link i gave you.. It shows how to do it.

Comment: Actually thst is for Windows Phone. States that in the Description. Have a look.
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Periodic-Background-Agent-1b562ebc

Comment: If this answer helped you out can you mark it as correct?